# How to center grid vertically and horizontally on Ionic 5?

Tags: css, ionic5

I don't know how to center the 4 icons on the center of the layout, it would be like 2 icons up and two down, im with ubuntu and cannot draw an example, sorry. The problem i have to deal with the CSS and don't have any idea. Thank you

[image]

My CSS at the moment:

```
.vertical-center {
    .fixed-content,
    .scroll-content {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        ion-grid {
            max-width: 300px; 
            width:100%; 
            margin: auto; 
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<ion-content class="vertical-center">

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="../../assets/fbicon.png" style="width:60px;" />
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="../../assets/igicon.png" style="width:60px;" />
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="../../assets/twittericon.png" style="width:60px" />
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="../../assets/mylogo.png" style="width:60px;" />
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Thats my goal:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your HTML & CSS?

Comment: @M.Mariscal They probably downvoted before your edits, when the question was very incomplete. Hopefully they return and see it's OK now, but maybe not, so it's better to post a good question in the first place.

Comment: Does anyone can help me? UPDATED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved:

I don't think its the best result but i can see much better centered on the screen so at the moment is my unique option.

//.SCSS

```
.square {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 1%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
  }
```

//HTML

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ion-grid class="square">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <img class="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown animate__slow" src="../../assets/icon1.png" style="width:60px;"/>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <img class="animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate__slow" src="../../assets/icon2.png" style="width:60px;"/>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <img class="animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__slow" src="../../assets/icon3.png" style="width:60px"/>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <img class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__slow" src="../../assets/icon4.png" style="width:60px;"/>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually style `ion-grid` or `ion-row` to center:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for a similar solution for Ionic v5 in React. Didn't find anything obvious, so adding it here for anyone dabbling in React.

Here is what worked for me:

```
export const CenteredContent = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <IonGrid style={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <IonRow class="ion-align-items-center" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                <IonCol class="ion-text-center">
                    {children}
                </IonCol>
            </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
    )
}
```

Puts content in the center without too much css (screenshot uses IonSpinner component for the children props):
[screenshot of what it looks like, since i am not allowed to embed images, yet...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHWKz.png)

Answer (score 0):

To center a content in Ionic 6, use the following...

```
<style scoped>
ion-content::part(scroll) {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}
</style>
```